# Google drive SDK: Cancel upload

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, request-cancelling

How to cancel file upload request with `Google Drive SDK`?

I'm creating .NET 4 task that calls

```
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, body.MimeType);
request.Upload();
```

I can't use cancellation token here to cancel my task and I can't find any method for cancelling request too. How should I stop the uploading process?\

**update**

Hello? Is there anybody?

Comment: can you help me in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672542/how-to-implement-google-drive-api-download-progress-bar-and-cancel-in-winforms-c Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google support is "awesome". I think even on `happy housewives club forum` I would get at least one answer.
I already know that this is not possible and I've added cancellation support to upload function myself, but guys, if you provide support you need to answer from time to time. This is not the first long time waiting for response from Google support.
[Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/support) you say that you support `Google Drive SDK` on Stack Overflow. You definitely need to improve your responsiveness.

For the rest of people who may be interested in.

I changed project to use .NET framework 4.0 and in file `Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs` added overload `CancellationToken token` parameter to the `Upload` function.

```
do
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // <----------------------
    bytesSent += SendChunk(contentStream, url, bytesSent);
    UpdateProgress(UploadStatus.Uploading, bytesSent);
} while (bytesSent < contentStream.Length);
```

Then added marked line to the upload loop.

To avoid having failed tests you may also overload `Upload` function like this

```
public void Upload()
{
    Upload(new CancellationTokenSource().Token);
}
```

That's it.

Comment: +1 Thanks dude....Good Job. Do you have any idea about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679444/upload-files-on-cloud-using-email-address